# How to stop a C++ blocking read call

Tags: c++, can-bus

I'm reading CAN-BUS traffic under SocketCAN and C++ in GNU/Linux. I've found that the read call is blocking, and I'm struggling to figure out how to stop my program properly when I don't want to keep reading.

Of course, I could hit `Ctrl+C` if I've invoked the program from the terminal, but the point is to find a way to do it programmatically when some condition is met (e.g., record for 5 seconds, or when some event happens, like a flag is raised). A timeout could work, or something like a signal, but I don't know how to do it properly.

```
// Read (blocking)
nbytes = read(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
```

Comment: Run the read in a thread or use a non-blocking read?

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: Linux. The read is actually being run in a thread. Should I just terminate the thread? Is there not a cleaner option? I didn't know about a non-blocking read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read is always blocking...   you want to only read if data is waiting... so consider doing a poll on the socket first to see if data is available and if so THEN read it.  You can loop over doing the poll until you no longer want to read anymore...

```
bool pollIn(int fd)
{
    bool returnValue{false};
    struct pollfd *pfd;
    pfd = calloc(1, sizeof(struct pollfd));
    pfd.fd = fd;
    pfd.events = POLLIN;

    int pollReturn{-1};
    pollReturn = poll(pfd, 1, 0);

    if (pollReturn > 0)
    {
        if (pfd.revents & POLLIN)
        {
            returnValue = true;
        }
    }
    free(pfd);
    return(returnValue);
}
```

The above should return if there is data waiting at the socket file descriptor.

```
while(!exitCondition)
{
  if(pollIn(fd))
  {
    nbytes = read(fd, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    // other stuff you need to do with your read
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like this approach. I'm trying to make that code work. I've changed the pfd declaration as non-pointer and removed the calloc so fd can be assigned to pfd.fd. But it still does not return true on can message events.  The pfd.revents & POLLIN check should include a double &&, right?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html.    The demo code uses the single &.  Basically, with single &, both elements get promoted to int and then evaluated... whereas with double &&, both conditions get downgraded to bool, and the later condition is only evaluated if the previous condition is true.  Not sure why poll is always returning false...  you may want to test for error and check ERRNO to see what's coming back

Comment: Ok, so it seems the solution was to set pfd.events = 1;

Comment: good call...  when i edited my code for this answer i forgot that line.. added in pfd.events = POLLIN;

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

Use a method like `select` or `epoll` to determine whether the socket has activity *before* beginning the `read`. Then it will not actually block.

The `select`/`epoll` call is itself blocking, but can be given a timeout so that you always have an escape route (or, in the case of `epoll`, the lovely `epollfd` for immediate triggering of a breakout).

Comment: > but can be given a timeout..

Or you use `epollfd` to stop the `select`/`epoll` from a separate thread. No timeout needed.

Comment: @sbabbi Oh yeah, or that. That's my preferred approach when using `epoll`. I use a timeout of 10s or so just to have an opportunity to fall out in case of "emergencies" (e.g. epollfd failed for some unknown reason)